# How to update the date and time in bootstrap datetimepicker when value of field changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am making a time conversion tool. As the bare minimum description I can say that it calculates the time of the city you give in comparison to other.

As you can see in the below image, what I want is to update the value of the bootstrap `datetimepicker` with the calculated time.

**Edit 1:** Basically when the value of field is updated using JavaScript the value of date for widget (`bootstrap-datetimepicker`) should also change.

**Edit 2:**

**Steps to check the problem**

- Choose the time for Pune city.
- Enter any cities name in the city one text field.
- The city one time field should now update.
- Now when you try to update the value in city one field you will observe that the value in field is not matching to the value in bootstrap datetimepicker.

[image: The screenshot of the problem]

You can check the code [here](http://github.com/udit96rc/TimeConverter) in  the `index.html` file.

You can check the tool [here](http://uditchugh.me/pt).

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @BenM Tried to update using the `defualtDate` option but I don't know much of jQuery so not sure whether I did it correctly and thus seeking some guidance.

Comment: So you want the datetimepicker to update as soon as you write into the textfield? your question is very unclear

Comment: @loli Yes I want it to update when the value of text field is changed after calculations in JavaScript.

Comment: you should provide the steps to see the problems and fix your javascript because it's buggy, page keeps freezing. Please make a jsfiddle too

Comment: @loli Please check the description now.